# How to link a rabbitMq container in docker-compose file?

Tags: docker

links:
     - "RMQ:RMQ"
The above line of code is used to link a RMQ container with the existing Container. While Running a composer file it produces the error like 
**ERROR: Service 'ContainerName' has a link to service 'RMQ:RMQ' which is undefined**.

But the RMQ container is defined insame docker-compose file...

Comment: Please provide some more information, like the content of the `docker-compose` file.

Comment: Please adjust your question to [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)